# In Google Maps, how do I find out the latitude and longitude of a point?

Tags: google-maps

I am interested in finding the latitude and longitude of a point on a map. How do I do so in Google Maps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In [Google Maps Labs](https://maps.google.com/maps?showlabs=1) are two features which can do that.

**LatLng Tooltip**

> Displays a tooltip next to the mouse cursor showing the latlng directly underneath it.

**LatLng Marker**

> Adds an option to the context menu that lets you drop a mini marker showing the latlng of the position that the cursor was pointing at when the context menu was evoked

Answer (score 8):

If you right click on the map and select 'What's Here?' from the context menu, a marker will appear and the coordinates will be placed in the search box at the top of the page.

Comment: I used this feature for a long time but it seems to have disappeared from the latest revision of Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just click the "Link" button on the upper right hand corner above the map.  This will generate a link that will contain the latitude and longitude of the center of the map as a query string parameter call "ll".

Answer (score 0):

There's a maplet extension you can add your "my maps" called "GPS Location" If you add that to your map and then click on a point. It will add a pin with the GPS info on it